# Windows 7 cygwin xterm: Xt error: Can't open display

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, xterm

There is no display available when I try to ssh from a Windows 7 system to Ubuntu.

When I do this:

```
ssh -X -c blowfish-cbc username@IP xterm
```

I get this error:

```
xterm Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm:  DISPLAY is not set
```

I have already tried the suggestions from [this AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61690/ssh-x-xt-error-cant-open-display-0-0) and this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468730/installing-cygwin-1-7-15-1-on-win-7).

Comment: You need Cygwin Xwin Server installed and running in your Windows for doing that.

Comment: ah yes! Actually I did install it but I hadn't restarted my system. After a restart it's working fine.